# DataGrid Hide DataRows scroll bar doesnt reflect visible datarows

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a datagrid displaying data and in the resources, I am using a datatrigger to set visibility of the datarow based on a boolean variable. The data Trigger hides/collapse the row but the scroll bar with the datagrid is not resized proportinal to the data showing on the screen. For Example in total if I have 100 rows that Im working with and I am hiding 80. The scroll bar will be sized like I am displaying the total 100 and not the 20 being displayed. Is there a way to change that, that scroll bar can be resized to what is being displayed as well as the hidden data rows not leave a foot print?

```
        <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource IsExcludedConverter},ConverterParameter='IsOnExclusionList'}" 
                                     Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />

                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding  Path=.,Converter={StaticResource IsExcludedConverter},ConverterParameter='IsOnExclusionList'}" 
                                     Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
```

Comment: if you remove <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" /> the problem occurs?

Comment: yes I just have collapse and its still their